# Returning different template specialisations from a function

Tags: templates, c++11

I have created a C++11 class in which I want to parse a string and return an object based on the data in the string. The object I want to return is defined as:

```
 // Container for the topic data and id
template <typename T> 
class Topic
{
public:
  Topic(string id, T data)
  : _id(id), _data(data)
  {}

private:
  string _id;
  T _data;
};
```

The function that returns the object is defined as:

// Parses a string and splits it into components

```
class TopicParser
{
public:
  template <class T>
  static Topic<T>
  parse(string message)
  {
    T data; // string, vector<string> or map<string, string>
    string id = "123";
    Topic<T> t(id, data);
    return t;
  }  
};
```

I (think I) would like to be able to call the function in this way:

```
string message = "some message to parse...";
auto a = TopicParser::parse<Topic<vector<string>>>(message);
auto b = TopicParser::parse<Topic<string>>(message);
```

but the compiler complains that:

```
no matching function for call to ‘Topic<std::vector<std::basic_string<char> > >::Topic()’
```

As you can tell, I'm not a templates expert. Is what I'm trying to do an approved way of using templates of should I prefer some other method?

Comment: you're declaring the `parse` method as static, I think the compiler will expect from you to define each and every specializations you wish to use in your code somewhere.

Comment: You are passing `Topic<something>` to `parse<T>` as the template argument. It returns `Topic<T>`. Do you want to get `Topic<Topic<something>>` back?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `Topic<vector<string>>` as template argument is useless here, I guess. Just remove `Topic`:

```
auto a = TopicParser::parse<vector<string>>(message);
auto b = TopicParser::parse<string>(message);
```

Comment: Yes, I misunderstood what I had defined T to represent. Thank you!